# Unable to sudo apt install a package

Tags: apt, package-management, json

I'm trying to install a json parser package for development in Ubuntu.

When I run `sudo apt-get install libcjson-dev` it's unable to locate.
How to fix this problem?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcjson-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcjson-dev
```

Thanks for any help!